# Numpy minimum with functional arg

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a way of computing a minimum index value of an array after application of a function (i.e. the equivalent of `matlab` find)?

In other words consider something like:

```
 a = [1,-3,-10,3]

 np.find_max(a,lambda x:abs(x))
```

Should return **2**.

I could write a loop for this obviously but I assume it would be faster to use an inbuilt `numpy` function if one existed.

Comment: Just use NumPy funcs `np.argmax(np.abs(a))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `argmax`, according to the documentation:

> numpy.argmax(a, axis=None, out=None)
>
> Returns the indices of
>   the maximum values along an axis.
>
> Parameters:    a : array_like Input array. axis : int, optional By
>   default, the index is into the flattened array, otherwise along the
>   specified axis. out : array, optional If provided, the result will be
>   inserted into this array. It should be of the appropriate shape and
>   dtype. Returns:    index_array : ndarray of ints Array of indices into
>   the array. It has the same shape as a.shape with the dimension along
>   axis removed. See also ndarray.argmax, argmin
>
> amax The maximum value along a given axis. unravel_index Convert a
>   flat index into an index tuple. Notes
>
> In case of multiple occurrences of the maximum values, the indices
>   corresponding to the first occurrence are returned.

```
import numpy as np

a = [1, -3, -10, 3]
print(np.argmax(np.abs(a)))
```

Output:

```
2
```